# Mailchimp embed form is resulting in 404 errors from my own CSS and JS files

Tags: jquery, html, express, handlebars.js, mailchimp

I'm trying to place Mailchimp's embed form on a site that uses handlebars partials, but it is causing my javascript and css files that were working before to return 404's.

I've tried placing the form on it's own handlebars partial but it always loads correctly but returns "net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" for my js and css files. The embed form uses a css link tag, its own style tag, and two script tags.

```html
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
    #mc_embed_signup {
        background: #fff;
        clear: left;
        font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }

    /* Add your own Mailchimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
  We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form
        action="RemovedSiteURL"
        method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank"
        novalidate>
        <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
            <h2>Subscribe</h2>
            <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text"
                    name="b_0aeb9493b3fec38b23388f11b_6846240915" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
            <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe"
                    class="button"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
<script
    type='text/javascript'>(function ($) { window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array(); fnames[0] = 'EMAIL'; ftypes[0] = 'email'; fnames[1] = 'FNAME'; ftypes[1] = 'text'; fnames[2] = 'LNAME'; ftypes[2] = 'text'; fnames[3] = 'ADDRESS'; ftypes[3] = 'address'; fnames[4] = 'PHONE'; ftypes[4] = 'phone'; }(jQuery)); var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

Expected: Place Mailchimp embed code into my already functional footer partial made with handlebars and that work.

Actual: Mailchimp's form loads it's scripts correctly but my own js and css files return "net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)".

img of network tab: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IW78I.jpg

Comment: it looks like the mailchimp stylesheet (Classic-10_7) is getting a 307 (temporary redirect) and not loading, and the rest of the files queued behind it just wait.  You may want to look at how Express prefers to handle static files.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for the help. If I'm understanding what you're talking about then the error is with Mailchimp's css link and not with my static files. I figured I should contact Mailchimp to figure out why the link is redirecting. I guess you mean I can change how my files are served to ensure they load even though Mailchimp's css file is not?

Comment: not exactly - I mean express.js expects you to include links to files a different way...  but you could also make sure your files are loading first (put them before the mailchimp files in your code...you'll probably still get the error, but your files would already be loaded.  Otherwise the link in my first comment may help you - try following those steps to get express to allow the mailchimp files to load.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the protocol `https:` part to the css & js includes:

```
<link href="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the mailchimp stylesheet that they provide the link to, copy and paste the css text into a new .css file and reference that file instead.

```html
<link href="mailchimp.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```